# Pause a Loop for Data Entry

Tags: delphi, loops, repeat, delphi-5

I am importing a list of items from a Text file and trying to use the manual Insert routines that the User has for individual data entries. But, with an Import, I need to pause each new entry for the User to manually assign it some other details before the Post. How do I pause the loop for each iteration? I can't use a MessagDlg as it is Modal and does not allow the User to change stuff before Posting it.

Pseudo code.

```
btnInsertClick;
begin
  DB.Insert;
  DB.FieldByName('Item').AsString:=StrList[aCtr];
end;

btnPostClick;
begin
  DB.Post;
  Inc(aCtr);
end;

btnCancelClick;
begin
  DB.Cancel;
  aCtr:=StrList.Count;
end;

ImportList;
begin
  StrList.LoadFromFile('TextFile.txt');
  aCtr:=0;
  repeat
    btnInsertClick;
// The User needs to be able to select data from 
// two drop-down-combos before Posting.
// I need to wait here for Post or Cancel to be clicked
  until aCtr = StrList.Count;
end;
```

Comment: Calling btnXXX.Click inside an import routine is absolutely the wrong way to go about it.  Design yourself a data-entry form for inputting/editing a single record in your DB table.  Then, write a routine which inserts a record from your StrList directly into the table, and then invokes your data entry form to edit/correct/complete/delete it.  Btw, is this a learning exercise or for a real-world application?

Comment: You've almost done it. Just remove that repeat-until loop and let the user do the rest. You load the data, set the counter aCtr to 0 and display the necessary additional info. The user will done the rest clicking on Post and Cancel buttons. Just keep the aCtr variable global for the form. And after post call some proc to display the data for the next record

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use the loop. Simply, when the button is clicked do the same as your are already doing now, plus prepare the data for the next input (increase `aCtr`, display the next prompt, set `ItemIndex` of the ComboBox to `-1`). If `aCtr >= StrList.Count` at this point — disable/hide the button, or close the form.